# Retrieve data from friday 7pm to current date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Retrive data from previous friday 7PM to current date.

Example: today date 17 April 6.59PM will retrive data from 10 April 7PM until 17April 6.59PM.

I just have idea something like this:-

```
case
  when to_char(sysdate, 'Day') = 'Saturday' then
   select ODAT_LOC where ODAT_LOC BETWEEN sysdate and sysdate -1
  when to_char(sysdate, 'Day') = 'Sunday' then
   select ODAT_LOC where ODAT_LOC BETWEEN sysdate and sysdate -2
  when to_char(sysdate, 'Day') = 'Monday' then
   select ODAT_LOC where ODAT_LOC BETWEEN sysdate and sysdate -3
  when to_char(sysdate, 'Day') = 'Tuesday' then
   select ODAT_LOC where ODAT_LOC BETWEEN sysdate and sysdate -4 
  when to_char(sysdate, 'Day') = 'Wednesday' then
   select ODAT_LOC where ODAT_LOC BETWEEN sysdate and sysdate -5 
  when to_char(sysdate, 'Day') = 'Thursday' then
   select ODAT_LOC where ODAT_LOC BETWEEN sysdate and sysdate -6 
  when to_char(sysdate, 'Day') = 'Friday' then
   select ODAT_LOC where ODAT_LOC BETWEEN sysdate and sysdate -7 
  when to_char(sysdate, 'Day') = 'Friday' then
   select ODAT_LOC where ODAT_LOC BETWEEN sysdate and sysdate  
  else
    ''
end ODAT_LOC
```

But unable to control on time.

Anyone have idea how to make it in oracle sql.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This will get you all rows from your table from the previous Friday 7pm. You don't need the CASE.

```
select * FROM YOURTABLE 
where ODAT_LOC >= (next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'FRI') - 7 + interval '19' hour)
```

I am assuming ODAT_LOC is of DATE type.

```
SQL> 
select sysdate, next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'FRI') from dual;

SYSDATE              NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDA
-------------------- --------------------
2020-04-16-THU 12:22 2020-04-17-FRI 00:00


SQL> 
select sysdate, next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'FRI') - 7 from dual;

SYSDATE              NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDA
-------------------- --------------------
2020-04-16-THU 12:22 2020-04-10-FRI 00:00


SQL> 
select sysdate, next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'FRI') - 7  + interval '19' hour from dual;

SYSDATE              NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDA
-------------------- --------------------
2020-04-16-THU 12:22 2020-04-10-FRI 19:00
```

Comment: wow. that is working for me. Thank you very much, help me on this. Just use next_day function and interval for hour. No need to use case.